# How to ignore first N rows in a CSV-file in Powershell

Tags: powershell, rest, csv

I have a CSV file were the first 9 rows contain text that is not part of the CSV-data. The headers for the columns are put on row 10 and subsequent rows (11+) contain the data. The file is fetched via rest.

How do I simply tell the Import-Csv cmdlet do this?

I have tried this:

```
$tempFile = New-TemporaryFile
$url = "some-url/data.csv""
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -OutFile $tempFile #Put CSV into file from Rest API
$f = Import-Csv -Path $tempFile -Delimiter ';' -Skip 9 -Header @("Datum", "Tid (UTC)", 
    "Lufttemperatur", "Kvalitet")
    $f | Select-Object { $_ | Select-Object Datum, 'Tid (UTC)', Lufttemperatur, Kvalitet}
```

i.e. I have tried to skip the first rows in the file. But, this doesn't seem to do the trick. What am I doing wrong here?

Any ideas are welcomed!
Kind regards,
Peter

Comment: How about using `Get-Content | Select-Object -Skip 9` and then using `ConvertFrom-CSV`?

Comment: If the writer of this file begins each of these 9 lines with a # character, Import-Csv will treat them as comments.  If you have control over your feed you might want to consider this.

Answer (score 2):

Solved!

The correct syntax for skipping the rows should be:

```
$f = Import-Csv -Path $tempFile -Delimiter ';' -Header @("Datum", "Tid (UTC)", "Lufttemperatur", "Kvalitet") | Select-Object -Skip 9
```

/P

Comment: If it works for you, all the better but this doesn't match with your question. `the first 9 rows contain text that is not part of the CSV-data. The headers for the columns are put on row 10 `

Comment: The type information is on line 1 by default. If you add ` -NoTypeInformation` to the `Import-CSV` command you can probably use `-Skip 10`

Answer (score 0):

Use `ConvertFrom-Csv`

```
Get-Content -Path $filePath |    <# Get lines #>
  Select-Object -Skip 11 |       <# Skip 11 lines #>
  ConvertFrom-Csv                <# Convert rest from CSV #>
```