# Use quotas as delim skipping two lines in batch script

Tags: quotes, skip

I'm stuck on a statement that I've already used multiple times with other delimiters.
I have to process a three-line TXT file, each line contains 26 fields **delimited by quotes**.
This is the file in which the second set is empty, it's a possible case:

```
ID="a1i7Q000000gTynQAE" Machine="TEST" Dept="TEST" ExecutionDate="2023/11/17" 
Set 1="O14" Time="2023/11/17 18:33:09" MeasurementMode="Rad" A1="40.96" A2="41.65" A1Lenght="177" n1="133.75" C1="527" CAD="2.48" LAT="4.43" L="23.88" RoN="12.52" Diam="5.23"/ 
Set S="152" Time="2023/11/17 18:33:09" MeasurementMode="Deg" A1="NaN" A2="NaN" A1Lenght="NaN" n1="132.14" C1="NaN" CAD="NaN" LAT="NaN" L="NaN" RoN="NaN" Diam="NaN"/
```

On the first pass I have to extract data %%A, %%H, %%J, %%L, %%N, %%P and so on ignoring the first row, on the second pass I have to ignore the first two rows.

The expected output for result1.txt is

```
a1i7Q000000gTynQAE
"VV_A1_c" : 40.96
"VV_j32_a" : 41.65
177
.....
```

The command lines I'm using are the following:

```
for /f tokens^=1-26^ skip^=1^ delims^="^ %%A in ("out1.txt") do (
 ECHO %%~A >>result1.txt
 ECHO "VV_A1_c" : %%~H >>result1.txt
 ECHO "VV_j32_a" : %%~J >>result1.txt
 ECHO %%~L >>result1.txt
 .....
```

and

```
for /f tokens^=1-26^ skip^=2^ delims^="^ %%A in ("out1.txt") do (
 ECHO %%~A >>result2.txt
 ECHO "VV_A1_c" : %%~H >>result2.txt
 .....
```

...but the result is always "Sintax error" or "not expected" no matter how I set the ^ delimiters.
Please can anyone tell me where I'm wrong?

Another question: if the fields become 30 what letters must I use after %%Z?

Comment: See docs: 1) https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html  2) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for

Comment: Please include a sample of the "out1.txt" file. (max 5 lines will do...)

Comment: After `%%Z`, see: [How to assign more than 26 variables with FOR Loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22867421/how-to-assign-more-than-26-variables-with-for-loop)

Comment: "I have to extract data %%A, %%H,...." Please do not let anyone guess about your expected output, and include your expected output....

Comment: Thank you for your answers, post edited adding out1.txt example

Comment: BTW: I did not know about using `^` as delimiter (never used it, and never had the **need** to use it!). This is show in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13217838/724039.  First test seems to indicate the `skip=` is not working with that syntax.

Comment: I think you are near the point where you have to ask yourself if a batch file in Windows is the right tool for the job. Maybe PowerShell is a better one ?  (But waiting for the 'expected output' .... )

Comment: I hope only NEAR, because this is part of a bigger work all developed with batch files.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to get it working using Windows batch:

```
@echo off

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set A=0
echo A:%a%::
for /f delims^=^"^ tokens^=1-26 %%B in (out1.txt) do (
    SET /A A=!A!+1
    IF !A! GEQ 2 (
         echo Line!A!:FieldB:%%B
         echo Line!A!:fieldC:%%C
         echo Line!A!:FieldD:%%D
         echo Line!A!:FieldZ:%%Z
         echo.
    )
)
```

output:

```
A:0::
Line2:FieldB:Set 1=
Line2:fieldC:O14
Line2:FieldD: Time=
Line2:FieldZ: Diam=

Line3:FieldB:Set S=
Line3:fieldC:152
Line3:FieldD: Time=
Line3:FieldZ: Diam=
```

- Above with help from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13217838/724039

But `skip=` need too much work-around and i am no-where near your expected output.

Maybe a simpler approach would be PowerShell:

```
Import-CSV out1.txt -Delimiter '"' -Header ('a','b','c','d') | Format-Table
```

output:

```
a      b                  c        d
-      -                  -        -
ID=    a1i7Q000000gTynQAE Machine= TEST
Set 1= O14                Time=    2023/11/17 18:33:09
Set S= 152                Time=    2023/11/17 18:33:09
```

For your expected output this might start with:

```
Import-CSV out1.txt -Delimiter '"' -Header ('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','VV_A1_c','i','VV_j32_a','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r') | Format-Table VV_A1_c,VV_j32_a,l,n,p
```

output:

```
VV_A1_c    VV_j32_a l   n      p
-------    -------- -   -      -
2023/11/17
40.96      41.65    177 133.75 527
NaN        NaN      NaN 132.14 NaN
```

And, a (steep?) learning curve towards PowerShell, which I am not too familiar with...

- [How to ignore first N rows in a CSV-file in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66744517/how-to-ignore-first-n-rows-in-a-csv-file-in-powershell)

Comment: Then instead of "skip" your code enumerates the row you are in by incrementing the variable A, this is a good workaround

Comment: I used that a a 'workaround' because I could not get `skip=` working.

Comment: implementing this part of code in my structure I always get "Sintax error" after     set A=0.

Comment: The script is an exact copy of what I have here on my Windows11 system, so I have no clue where you Syntax Error is coming from...

Comment: I don't know why but, trying to solve the new "Sintax error" all of my original code started working properly. .. and without any kind of change!!
IT mysteries...
Thank you Luuk